# Google App Engine With Twilio: ImportError: No module named pytz

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twilio, pytz

I am trying to integrate Twilio with google app engine. I followed the instructions found here: http://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/appengine.html.

When I try to run the app locally or deploy the app i get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

the error is coming from the path:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from .rest.exceptions import TwilioRestException
from .resources
from .util
import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

I am have done a ton of research in to resolving my problems, but cannot seem to find a solution. I have used easy_install to reinstall the pytz .egg file, but that does not seem to do anything; even when i remove it from the easy_install.pth file andthen reinstall it. The weird thing is that if i access python from the command line, and try to import pytz, i get no error:

```
$ python
>>> import pytz
```

*no error*

any and all solution or tips would be appreciated! thanks in advance!
brandon

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use 3rd party libraries not listed in this document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27, You have to move the library dir to the root of your appengine project.

In this case you have to copy `pytz` library folder to the root of your appengine project.